# Creating transition states for a second order Markov Chain for Attribution

Tags: markov-process

I'm pretty new to Markov Chains, and I'm exploring them for attribution. I'd like to play around with higher orders but I'm a little confused on how to do this.

Most resources I can find show a second order transition matrix like:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | - | - |
| AB | - | - |
| BA | - | - |
| BB | - | - |

However I am struggling to understand this. If the path could be for example

```
"B" -> "A" -> "B" -> "B" -> Convert
```

would I not want the transition to the next pair? So in the example, the user has gone from B to A, so they would be at "BA". Would the possible next states (/columns) not be `AA` (if moved to A), `AB` (if moved to B) and `Convert` (if they convert)?

Assuming the same probability for each transition from the state, a transition matrix like below makes sense to me:

|  | start | A | B | AA | AB | BA | BB | Convert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| start | 0. | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0. |
| A | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| B | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| AA | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| BB | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| BA | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| BB | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| Convert | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0. | 0. | 1. |

Would that be correct (though probably able to simplified)?

Also, do I have to consider the final state of a pair to be the first state of the next pair, or should they not overlap? e.g. for path `A -> B -> C -> B -> C -> Convert`, should that be:

- `AB -> CB -> CConvert (-> stays in Convert)` or,
- `A -> AB -> BC -> CB -> BC -> Convert`

Comment: Hi Liam, this seems like an interesting question but I think we need some more context to answer. Your use of A, B and Convert seems to suggest there is a particular use case or resource which you have in mind. Can you give some more details?